# Typescript doesn't showing any error for non exist field in array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

When I'm trying to push an object into an array with some extra field, typescript throws an error as expected.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const arr2: Person[] = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 27 },
  { name: "Bob", age: 28 },
];

arr2.push({ id: 1, name: "Carl", age: 30 }); // 'id' does not exist in type 'Person'
```

But when I assign that same object into another variable and push that variable into an array typescript not shows any error but I'm expecting the same error which giving for the first code snippet.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const arr2: Person[] = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 27 },
  { name: "Bob", age: 28 },
];

const data = { id: 1, name: "Carl", age: 30 };

arr2.push(data);
```

Comment: This has to do with a feature called "excess property checking" on TypeScript: when passing a variable into a function, the type checks are more relaxed for legacy reasons: historically functions can receive arbitrary properties that are more what it is defined to accept.